# How to create Sticker Keyboard App in android & IOS

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, emoji

I am trying to develop an App that with custom Keyboard in both Android & IOS.

With that custom keyboard i could send sticker or image through whatsApp, Instagram etc.

I need to develop a keyboard with following design

[image]

I tried some example in android from https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615.

it is working fine but it showing keyboard with alphanumeric character.

Actually need show custom images.

so is there any suggestion or tutorial available, please help me.

Comment: any success sending stickers?

Answer (score -1):

For IOS have a look at https://github.com/SamuelZhaoY/ios-emojikeyboard and study.